# Network chart nodes relation nodes merging -> highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

im working on network graph highcharts 
each node should have a new child but it should not merge with another subnode if its has the same name, like child1, child2, child3, pointing to subchild1,for each individual we should have the individual nodes pointing to each one

fiddle link ->    https://jsfiddle.net/GnanaSagar/36k2wmry/1/
[image]

Comment: Well.... I suppose `subchild1.1` could be a good enough workaround?

Comment: but for my requirement its not possible the subchild will be same for almost all the time but it should not be merged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `formatter` function for data labels:

```
series: [{
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: undefined,
        formatter: function() {
            if (this.key.indexOf('subchild') >= 0) {
                return 'subchild1'
            }
            return this.key
        }
    },
    data: [...,
        {
            from: 'child1',
            to: 'subchild1'
        },
        {
            from: 'child2',
            to: 'subchild2'
        },
        {
            from: 'child3',
            to: 'subchild3'
        }
    ]
}]
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n4gd8v3r/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.dataLabels.formatter

Comment: thanks man,can i put icons for node based  on the levels like,level 1 should have the one icon and level 2 have another icon like that

Comment: Hi Gnana, I am glad I could help. To set different `marker` options for each level, you should use `nodes`, like in solution from @AVAVT: https://jsfiddle.net/y96u2cmj/

Comment: is it possible with out using subchild1.1 etc , bcoz im getting the values from java , so im unable to predict the values , so if i have 'n' levels and if we have two nodes have the same values those are pointing to single node i want a two nodes of the same values pointing individually .

Comment: @Gnana, It is necessary to use individual `to` values, but you can convert your data before creating the chart. I can help you if you will provide me with your sample data.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently [series.networkgraph.nodes](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.nodes) works.

```js
series: [{
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    data: [
            {from: 'parent', to: 'child1'},
            {from: 'parent', to: 'child2'},
            {from: 'parent', to: 'child3'},
            {from: 'child1', to: 'subchild1.1'},
            {from: 'child2', to: 'subchild2.1'},
            {from: 'child3', to: 'subchild3.1'}
    ],
    nodes: [{
        id: 'subchild1.1',
        name: 'subchild1'
      },
      {
        id: 'subchild2.1',
        name: 'subchild1'
      },
      {
        id: 'subchild3.1',
        name: 'subchild1'
      }
    ]
  }]
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9g42nqza/ (I have to comment out some of your original code because it was throwing error).